# Show that $z''+F(z') + z=0$ has a unique, stable periodic solution.

Tags: mathematical-modeling

The entire question reads:

Let $F$ satisfy the hypothesis of Lienard's Theorem. Show that $z'' + F(z') + z = 0$ has a unique, asymptotically stable, periodic solution. We're also given a hint to let $x = z'$ and let $y = -z$.

After some thought, I realize we probably want to get the equation to look like $x'' + F(x) x' + g(x) = 0$ (a system that we can apply Lienard's Theorem to), but I don't see how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The hint gives you directly the [Lienard system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard_equation#Li%C3%A9nard_system) if you write it $x'=z''=y-F(x)$ and $y'=-z'=-x$.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I had thought about it for a while and realized the problem I had was a typo with my $y'$. It all works out now. It was actually very obvious as you said.